# list of 2D to 3D using dstack

Tags: python-2.7, list, numpy

I have a list of 2D numpy arrays of length 2000.

I am trying to create a 3D array using dstack.  But it gives me the below error.

> return _nx.concatenate([atleast_3d(_m) for _m in tup], 2)
>
> ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

I manually checked the shapes of the 2D arrays, and all are of shape (3,300).  I am not sure what is wrong.

My code is very simple

```
   X = list()
   for row in df.itertuples(name=None):
        srow = [ "%s" %x for x in row[2:-1] ]
        exist_words = [word for word in srow if word in model ]
        X.append(model[exist_words])
    return np.dstack(X)
```

Comment: You're code isn't enough here, please provide a [mcve] with data.

Comment: Are you sure that the results of each `model[exist_words]` expression have the same shape? It seems like they could easily vary due to the `if word in model` condition in the list comprehension your using to construct `exist_words `

Comment: @tel I manually checked it and it is (3,300) for all the elements

Comment: That doesn't make a great deal of sense. You're going to have to do what @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ said and post some more code. At least enough for others to reproduce the error that you're getting

Comment: Use `[x.shape for x in X]` to verify the shape of all elements. `np.array(X)` might also be instructive.  If the shapes do match it should produce a (2000, 3,300) array.  If not, it may raise an error (`sequence`) or produce a (2000,) object dtype array.